# Fade out lightbulb 220V

Tags: arduino-uno, mosfet

I am trying to make a lightbulb fade to dark and back to light, for which I found the following tutorial online:
http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/
Unfortunately, the tutorial makes use of a 60V light source while my intention is to use the system on 220V. Would it be enough to solve my problem to replace the 60V MOSFET in the system with one of 220V?
What would otherwise be a solution?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the actual question being asked is about mains powered dimming circuits, not about Arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. Not under any circumstances.

Dimming AC is a considerably harder task, and doing it with 220VAC can be deadly.

To do it you need:

- A zero-crossing detection circuit
- A TRIAC driver circuit
- A suitable TRIAC to do the switching
- Software that will use the zero crossing information to time the switch-on of the TRIAC to a certain point in the waveform.

And most importantly:

**Good knowledge of working with mains electricity - without which you will probably kill yourself or those around you.**

Comment: a solid state relay w/zero cross is going to be the simplest way to accomplish all that.

Comment: @dandavis No, it's not. Not unless the ssr and the zero cross are completely separate units. You need to switch the SSR at a period *after* the zero cross to dim it. SSRs with zero crossing built in turn *on* at the zero crossing to prevent spikes.

Comment: of course, duh. i somehow forgot about the dimming part and focused on the safe part...

Answer (score 1):

You can buy 220V dimmer modules controllable with 5V PWM from Arduino. [Here is one](https://www.kemo-electronic.de/en/Transformer-Dimmer/Controller/Modules/M012-Power-Control-110-240-V-AC-1200-VA.php) controllable with [this PWM digital potentiometer module.](https://www.kemo-electronic.de/en/Transformer-Dimmer/Converter/M150-DC-pulse-converter.php)

I use Kemo 4000VA regulator module with that M150 digital pot module controlled with Arduino PWM for heater regulation.

[image]